# Angular javascript data that is nested objects I cannot seem to get d.data.Array[2] to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I had been using a angular service in which the data was returning just fine.
However, I wanted to instead call directly to the json file except now it doesn't like the data.

**Working version**

**Controller code:**

```
var confirm = this;
confirm.booking = airConfirmationService.getTestData();
```

**Service code :**

```
.factory('airConfirmationService', airConfirmationService);
var confirm = {};
confirmed.getTestData = function () {
    return {
        "flightData": [
          {
          "MultiCarrier": false,
          // etc...
```

However I am switched to a service with .service and calling the location of the .json file up directly.

**Not working**   ( well, it pulls the data but returns in a way that I don't understand)

```
.service('airConfirmationService', function ($http) {

        this.getTestData = function () {
            return $http({
                url: '../apps/temp/Api_Responses/confirm.booking.json',
                method: "GET"
            })
        }

    });
```

**Then in controller**

```
var confirm = this;
confirm.booking = airConfirmationService.getTestData();
console.log(confirm.booking)   // Picture attached shows how the data looks

// My attempt at getting "at" the data ... 
//var temp = [];
//temp = airConfirmationService.getTestData();
//confirm.booking = temp.d.Data;
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

While this code below "works" I have a feeling that not doing "q" /defer  / .then will be bad...

This code works in the controller calling the service, but how can i add/change to have  q/defer and/or  .then ?

```
 var getData = airConfirmationService.getTestData();
        getData.success(function(data) {
            confirm.booking = data;
        });
```

Comment: look into $q and $q.defer() .. you need to return promises.

Comment: `$http` is async and returns a promise, you need to use `.then()` to get the data after it has been returned from the server.

Comment: But it seems that I am getting the "data" based on the image I posted, right?      I am trying to get at it with  .d.Data.   but that is not working , why does the console.log show the structure with the flightData: Array[2]  with all the data  ... but I can't get at it?

Comment: no, you misunderstand what you are seeing.  `$http` is fast enough that when you output to the console, the result is returned by the time you get to the console and expand the view.  However, when you try to read the data in your code, your code doesn't know to wait, and is trying to get the data back *instantly*.  That's what `.then()` is for, to wait until the promise is finished.

Comment: Ok, how can I use the .then in the controller?    What I did that "works" is add a .success in the controller calling it.   Will then be a back idea,  I am going to post the code in the question at bottom under UPDATE:

Comment: `.success()` will work, but it is deprecated, `.then()` is the current standard not just in angular but in other promise libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular `$http` is Asynchronous.  The network operation to get the data from the server may take some time, so angular does not expect your app to wait until the operation is complete, stuck hung until the data is available.  Therefore, a promise object is used as a placeholder for the data.  Promises have a `.then()` function which tells the promise that it should execute some other code after the operation is complete.  They also provide a `.catch()` function for when something goes wrong and the data isn't returned.

The correct way to use `$http` is:

```
var confirm = this;
confirm.testData = {};
airConfirmationService.getTestData()
.then(function(response) {
    confirm.testData = response.data;
})
.catch(function(){
    //something went wrong
});
```

Comment: thx!   The strange issue with both my code and yours is that console.log(confirm.booking)     ( i altered yours)     - both output to chrome console as      -->     confirm.booking - Object  - _proto_  

Without any data tree to even look at  even though the data is getting hydrated to the UI ...   thoughts?

Comment: That happens because of the blank declaration `confirm.booking = {}`.  The service is called, and then the `console.log` output is of the object the moment it is called.  If you removed this blank declaration, then a `console.log` *outside* the `.then()` would be `undefined`, since the property isn't even defined at that stage.  If, however, you `console.log` *inside* the `.then()`, it will be whatever is returned, no matter if you had a blank declaration or not.

Comment: the original code (without `.then` or `.success`) only showed the promise object because you were assigning the promise to the `.booking` object, immediately before the `console.log`.  with the promises, you aren't re-assigning the `.booking` object until after the `console.log` has already output the empty object.

Comment: ok, I was just thinking about this before reading your 2 comments.   So should I actually want to assign the promise to the .booking object instead as it seems that it would be nice/ideal for the data to "live" longer  or not really?

Comment: No, that doesn't really make sense.  The thing I think you are finding confusing is that `console.log` is *instant*, while `$http` is *delayed*.  So when you use `console.log` to try to output the data (except for the original code, where you were actually outputting the `$http` itself instead of your data), you are always going to see the data as it is **the moment the `console.log` is called**.